# Are all SGS phones able to detect a car dock?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, car-dock

I have a Samsung Galaxy S I-9000 (the international version) and I have a car dock manufactured by Samsung for this phone (given to me by the Samsung representative who works with my cellphone provider, so I have good reason to believe it's the real thing).

I know that most car docks have a magnet that the phone uses to detect that it's been docked.  Mine seems to have one because when the phone is docked, the magnetic compass always points north, and when it's not docked, the compass points in the right direction (I checked this using [Car Dashboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.mandaria.cardashboardfree), which uses the internal compass when the phone isn't moving).

The problem is, my phone does not seem to detect that the phone is docked.  I have some triggers in [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) for when the car is docked, as well as in [Car Dashboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.mandaria.cardashboardfree), and they don't seem to work.

The question is, should me phone detect the car dock?  How can I check this? If it should, but doesn't, how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Checkout the "Car Home" App from Samsung, which can be found in the Samsung Apps App. I assume that this App is designed to work with the genuine Samsung Car Dock. IIRC someone told me that the App is able to detect that the smartphone has been docked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test that the triggers work like they should with Dock Simulator ([Market link](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.geekherd.dockenabler)). Run it and try "Car dock" to see what should happen when you dock the phone. If nothing happens, it might be a problem in your triggers. Otherwise, it's the dock or your phone's magnetic sensor. Try dialing `*#0*#` and selecting `Magnetic` to access a self test of the magnetic sensor.

Comment: I installed the Dock Simulator, and I see that when I "dock" it in the car, the triggers work as expected.  The self test said that the magnetic sensor test passed.  Any ideas?  How can I check the dock?

Comment: Probably should test the dock with another phone or your phone in another dock, besides that I can't help any further. Except that it seems weird that the dock would mess up the internal compass, since that would affect navigation/GPS...

Comment: In fact the SGS detects the presence of a car dock by checking for a 619k Ohm resitor between PIN 4 and 5. See also: http://www.android-hilfe.de/zubehoer-fuer-samsung-galaxy-s/60473-automodus-mit-ladekabel-dockingstation.html (in german)
The magnet solutions sounds counterproductive since the SGS uses the  magnetic sensor for direction and location determination.

Comment: @Flow: Good to know, just makes me wonder what is the purpose of the magnetic sensor in docks then, especially if it doesn't improve the compass functionality but rather impedes it...

Comment: That's odd, because my car dock is 100% mechanical.  there's no plug, no connector, no nothing.  It's just a plastic clip.

Comment: Well, I assumed we are talking here about the only car dock from samsung for the 
Galaxy S that I am aware of (that is sold in Europe): ECS-V968 http://www.google.de/search?q=ECS-V968&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1676&bih=959

Comment: I don't even know the model... the Samsung rep happened to be in the store when I was there, he saw my wife and I were buying two SGSes and he gave us a gift of a car dock